# How to create solana devnet wallet with python?

Tags: python, solana

I am trying to create wallet with Solathon lib:

```
 kp = Keypair()
```

then im trying to find this wallte in explorer and its saying that there is not such account. So how to create solana wallet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an account to show up as "created", it needs some SOL in it at least. Try sending SOL to that address!

```
solana --url devnet transfer --allow-unfunded-recipient <WALLET_PUBLIC_KEY> <AMOUNT>
```